# librdkafka partition.assignment.strategy add new strategy

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

Today with librdkafka there are two options for ***partition.assignment.strategy*** [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md):  range and round-robin.
I am looking if there is a way to add a custom assignment strategy.

Bests

Comment: You mean without recompiling librdkafka?

Answer (score 1):

There is also another one strategy, too. A newer strategy is called **Sticky** that was added in version **0.11.0**. One of the major reasons that it came about is to not only try and distribute topic partitions as evenly as possible, but also to have partitions stay with their existing consumers if possible.

Of course, **you can also create your own strategy**. Currently, `AbstractPartitionAssignor` is an abstract class that does some of the common work with mining data about topics to help implement your logic.
This [blog](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3) explains custom assignment strategy.

Answer (score 1):

As of today (Jun. 18, 2021), it is not supported yet by librdkafka.

You can find the feature request here:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/2284

You can only choose from one of the 3 built-in strategies (range, roundrobin, cooperative-sticky).
Documented here:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md